# Clear the cache of all manipulations of an image using Intervention/ImageCache with Laravel

Tags: php, caching, laravel

I'm trying to work out a way to clear the cache of all manipulations of an image that have been created using Intervention/ImageCache's manipulation templates (and likely in the future the cache function as well).

I have a some manipulation templates that run a custom filters on the image:

```
'thumbnail' => function($image) {
    return $image->filter(new ImageFilters\Fit(150));
},
```

The filter gets the focal point from the database and then runs the appropriate functions, using the focal point for the position as needed.

```
public function applyFilter(Image $image)
{
    $fp = Media::where('file_name', $image->filename)->pluck('focal_point');
    $fp = $fp ?: 'center';
    return $image->fit($this->width, $this->height, function(){return true;}, $fp);
}
```

This all works fine, but when the focal point is changed by the user the image isn't updated because of the cache. I need a way of clearing the cache for that specific image across the board.

From what I can tell each manipulated image is given its own unique cache key made up of an md5 hash, but I can't find any way of targeting all manipulations of a single image.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question lies quite in the past, I would like to present a solution:

```
// get an instance of the ImageCache class
$imageCache = new \Intervention\Image\ImageCache();

// get a cached image from it and apply all of your templates / methods
$image = $imageCache->make($pathToImage)->filter(new TemplateClass);

// remove the image from the cache by using its internal checksum
Cache::forget($image->checksum());
```

Execute this lines whenever you make a change to your image which affects the applied filters (e.g. a focal point).
When the cached image is requested, it will be created again with new values.

Hope this helps, 
Richard

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm! I got stuck for an about an hour trying to make this work on artisan cli but the trick was to run this through the web route! Hope this helps for anyone who gets stuck too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the cache for one image is not possible. The string for the focal_point must be in the callback signature, to take effect on the caching.

You can do this, by adding it to the Filter, by GET parameter for example.

```
'thumbnail' => function($image) {
    $fp = Input::get('fp', 'center');
    return $image->filter(new ImageFilters\Fit(150, $fp));
},
```

Then request your image like this:

```
/imagecache/thumbnail/foo.jpg?fp=center
```